# Fast way to decode RGB image in python

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, image-processing

I have a PNG image with the dimensions `1024x1024` that contains RGB encoded elevation data.
I read in the image using `asarray` from `numpy`:

```
rgb_data = np.asarray(image)
```

Which results in an 3D array with dimensions `(1024, 1024, 4)`. (I'm using RGBA)

I need to run some filters (gaussian, median) over that data, but I need to run it on the decoded elevation data.

The elevation data can be decoded with the following function:

```
def decodeRGB(pixel):
    return (pixel[0] * 256 + pixel[1] + pixel[2] / 256) - 32768
```

After decoding I will have a 2D array with dimensions `(1024, 1024)` that contains the decoded elevation data. (The actual height above sea level)

What I have so far is this:

```
rgb_data = np.asarray(image)
decoded_data = np.zeros(tile.size)

for rownum in range(width):
    for colnum in range(height):
        decoded_data[rownum][colnum] = decodeRGB(rgb_data[rownum][colnum])
```

Unfortunately this solution is quite slow. It takes approx. 10 seconds for a 1024 by 1024 image.

Is there a more performant way to implement this?

My main issue is that the dimensions of the array changes.
I'm going from a `(1024, 1024, 4)` array to a `(1024, 1024)` array.

I'm basically looking for a fast/efficient way to apply a function to every RGB pixel in an image which allows reduction of the array size.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Python isn't good choice for reading, calculating image pixel data . Get a `LOW_LEVEL` language !

Comment: @dsgdfg Sure, pure Python isn't known for its speed, but that's why Numpy is popular: it can operate on multidimensional arrays of machine-native data using compiled code, so the arithmetic and looping happens at compiled speed, _not_ at the rather sluggish pace of Python bytecode that's manipulating Python objects on a virtual machine.

Comment: `64 Bit machine ram address + Virtual ram address + Main Thread ram address + Sub thread ram address` Maybe work on @Sandro projects but not all time.. Save ram addresses in to ram, why more manufacturer produces `PCI card calculator module` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take advantage of vectorisation:

```
r = rgb_data[..., 0]
g = rgb_data[..., 1]
b = rgb_data[..., 2]
decoded_data = (256*r + g + b/256) - 32768
```

For example `rgb_data[..., 0]` selects *all* `1024x1024` red values at once, `256*r` multiplies all of them with 256 in one go, and so forth. Since the interpreted for loops in your code come with a significant overhead avoiding them should drastically speed up the conversion.

Or you could use a one-liner:

```
decoded_data = (rgb_data[..., :3] * (256, 1, 1/256)).sum(axis=-1) - 32768
```

There are yet more ways similar in spirit. Look at the comments on this post for a nice collection of one-liners.

Comment: Or even just `rgb_data @ [256, 1, 1/256, 0] - 32768`

Comment: @Eric :-) But multiplying and adding all those zeros is such a waste. Still, very pretty!

Comment: Then go with `rgb_data[..., :3] @ [256, 1, 1/256] - 32768`. Should use less memory than building the whole thing then summing

Comment: @Eric A work of art. Mind if I add that to the post?

Comment: Not very *artistic* I suppose, but a bit more performant one : `np.tensordot(rgb_data[...,:3], [256, 1, 1/256], axes=((-1,0))) - 32768`.

Comment: @Divakar: I'm surprised that `tensordot` is more performant than `@`

Comment: @PaulPanzer: Go for it

Comment: @Eric the `@` operator was only added very recently. The corresponding way to do that for python version < 3.5 is `rgb_data[..., :3].dot([256, 1, 1/256]) - 32768`

Comment: @rob: yep, my question was really why `tensordot` over just `dot`. But a good point to raise

Answer (score 3):

You can vectorize the process using the very powerful `np.einsum`.  Just make a transform vector out of your coefficients.

```
def decodeRGBArray(rgb_data):
    transf = np.array([256., 1., 1./256., 0.])
    return np.einsum('ijk,k->ij', rgb_data, transf) - 32768
```